# Exception Handlind | HttpMessageNotReadableException on Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

I'm trying to handle this exception by following some guides, but I can't manage to do it according to other's solutions.
Everytime I try to run it the way I have I get :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'handlerExceptionResolver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception with message: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException]: {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.proj.my.advice.ApplicationExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception), public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest) throws java.lang.Exception}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:652) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:640) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at com.proj.my.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception with message: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException]: {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.proj.my.advice.ApplicationExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception), public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest) throws java.lang.Exception}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException]: {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.proj.my.advice.ApplicationExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception), public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest) throws java.lang.Exception}
        at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.addExceptionMapping(ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.java:114) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.<init>(ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.java:78) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.initExceptionHandlerAdviceCache(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:276) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.afterPropertiesSet(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:243) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:1063) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.handlerExceptionResolver(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Basically I get the HttpMessageNotReadableException everytime I try to create a product with a "String" price instead of a float, and it's correct, you can't create one with such price, it needs to be a float, however i don't want to get this when I try it :

```
{
    "type": "about:blank",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "instance": "/cloudproduct"
}
```

I want to get a message.
Isn't this what I'm supposed to do ?

```
package com.proj.my.advice;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@RestControllerAdvice
public class ApplicationExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
   
   @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
   public ResponseEntity handleException(Exception e){
       return new ResponseEntity("error", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
   }

}
```

Comment: "ResponseEntityExceptionHandler" already maps many exceptions to correct methods, just override "handleHttpMessageNotReadable" method from "ResponseEntityExceptionHandler" class and write your logic inside it

Comment: Best practice is using @ExceptionHandler on exceptions which are not mapped by spring framework like custom exceptions

Comment: Okay! Thanks, I'll practice it.